# Importing two or more .dat in Pyomo

Tags: import, pyomo

I am using Pyomo and I want to import two or more data files (extension .dat). How can I do it?

I just know how to import one of it, like this:

```
instance = model.create_instance('datos1.dat')
```

Thanks, 
María

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DataPortal` object. E.g.,

```
model = AbstractModel()
...

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename="f1.dat", model=model)
data.load(filename="f2.dat", model=model)
instance = model.create_instance(data)
```

Comment: I tried it, but i get the next Error: TypeError: load() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)   Any idea?

Comment: Sorry. I had some typos in my code. I've updated my answer.